# Trying to use JFreeChart using JSP/Servles; issues with JDBCCategoryDataset and CategoryDataset

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart

i am trying to connect to a database and execute a query in a servlet. I am following this example [JFreeChart Example](http://read.pudn.com/downloads79/ebook/302101/JDBCCategoryChartDemo.java__.htm). If you look at the `readData()` method, it returns a `CategoryDataset` when it originally was a `JDBCCategoryDataset`. I get an error until i cast it do a `CategoryDataset`. When i run the code, it doesn't work, telling me it cannot cast. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Because [`JDBCCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html) implements the `CategoryDataset` interface, no cast should be required in the assignment: `CategoryDataset data = readData();` I get the following chart from the variation of `readData()` outlined below. I suspect that you have another problem.

[image: chart]

```
private CategoryDataset readData() { 

    JDBCCategoryDataset data = null; 
    Connection con; 
     try { 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test", "", ""); 
        data = new JDBCCategoryDataset(con); 
        String sql = "select TYPE_NAME, PRECISION "
            + "from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TYPE_INFO "
            + "where PRECISION BETWEEN 1 AND 12"; 
        data.executeQuery(sql); 
        con.close(); 
    } 
    … 
    return data; 
 }
```