# Can set data to a DefaultCategoryDataset from a vector?

Tags: vector, jfreechart

i wanna create a line chart from my database that shows the sales in monthly wise.
can i make it using a vector like this??
i'm so new to java

```
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add("60");
    v.add("values");
    v.add("student1");


    dataset.addValue(v);



    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("parameter values", "parameter", "values", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
     CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
       p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.black);
```

Comment: Why not start with the examples cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) and seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20ChartFactory.createLineChart%20DefaultCategoryDataset)?

Comment: Why use [`Vector`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/261156) at all?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland i get my data from a mysql table... :) i figured anyway i use a for loop and use my vector  DefaultCategoryDataset dataset object :)

Comment: Why not `JDBCCategoryDataset` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26942183/261156)?