# Jfreechart and jdbc.CategoryDataset

Tags: jdbc, jfreechart

My goal is to write a small program that reaches into our Public Safety database and retrieves ambulance response times. Then I want to take that data and generate a histogram.
I am having a very difficult time getting JFreechart to print a histogram of ambulance response times. When I run my code Netbeans generates an error message stating:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCCategoryDataset cannot be cast to org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset
>       at EMSResearch.histogram1.main(histogram1.java:39)
>   C:\Users\kulpandm\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this issue. If I can get a histogram to print out I can then move on and hack away at making it look good for my reports. Shown below is my code:

```
package EMSResearch;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset;

public class histogram1
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
{

    try
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://MyURL;database=MyDatabase;integratedsecurity=false;user=MyUser;password=MyPassword");
        //dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(conn);
        String query = "SELECT PUN_UnitID\n"
                + ", DATEDIFF(SECOND, IIU_tenroute, IIU_tArrive) AS [ResponseTime]\n"
                + "FROM IIncidentUnitSummary\n"
                + "WHERE IIU_tDispatch > 'may 15, 2016'\n"
                + "AND PUN_UnitID LIKE 'M[0-4]_'\n"
                + "AND IIU_tEnroute IS NOT NULL\n"
                + "AND IIU_tArrive IS NOT NULL\n"
                + "AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, IIU_tEnroute, IIU_tArrive) BETWEEN 0 AND 1800";
        JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(conn, query);
        dataset.executeQuery(query);
        conn.close();
        //the following blows up.
        JFreeChart chart;
        chart = ChartFactory.createHistogram("data", "ws range", "freq", (IntervalXYDataset) dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, false, false);
        int width = 560;
        int height = 370;
        File histChart = new File("c:\\histChart2.jpeg");

        try
        {
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(histChart, chart, width, height);
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(chart2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Can you please show me what I am doing incorrectly?
What can I do to fix this? (please be specific since I am not an expert programmer).

Answer (score 2):

A [`CategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/CategoryDataset.html) is *not* an [`IntervalXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/IntervalXYDataset.html); they provide completely different things to clients.

A `CategoryDataset` *can* be used to create a bar chart. Invoking `ChartFactory.createBarChart()` using your `JDBCCategoryDataset` should at least give you something to see. Refer to this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26941621/230513).

The [API](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html) suggests "writing your own code to read data from a `ResultSet`." I'd use the data to populate a [`HistogramDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/HistogramDataset.html), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513). Because `HistogramDataset` implements `IntervalXYDataset`, it is suitable for use with [`ChartFactory.createHistogram()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createHistogram-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset-org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation-boolean-boolean-boolean-). Where the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513) has one series for each primary color, it looks like you might want one series for each `PUN_UnitID`.

Conceptually, it may be easier to `SELECT DISTINCT PUN_UnitID` that meet your `LIKE` clause in an initial query. Then query the [response time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3528219/230513) values for each `PUN_UnitID` and invoke `dataset.addSeries(PUN_UnitID, values, bins)`.

Alternatively, loop through the `ResultSet`, adding entries to a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`, where the key is the `PUN_UnitID` the value is a`List` of [response times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3528219/230513). Use the `Map` entries to construct the `HistogramDataset` as before.

If latency becomes a problem, update the dataset in using a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).