# Barchart using database doesn't show

Tags: java, mysql, jfreechart

I want to create a chart using mysql database with Jfreechart, this is the code i used :

```
try {
    String query = 
        "Select id,Prop_menages_Urbains_Proprietaires from fes";

    JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = 
        new JDBCCategoryDataset(
            DBConnection.DBConnection(),
            query
        );

    JFreeChart chart = 
            ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "test", 
                "id", 
                "Prop_menages_Urbains_Proprietaires",
                dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, 
                false, 
                true, 
                true
            );

    BarRenderer render = null;

    CategoryPlot plot = null;

    render = new BarRenderer();

    ChartFrame fram = 
        new ChartFrame("test", chart);

    fram.setVisible(true);
    fram.setSize(600,650);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Erreur: " + ex);
}
```

after the execution the barchart doesn't show up although there are no errors in the code syntax 
any help please ?

UPDATE: i tried the same code but this time i used other columns from the database and it worked , what's the issues with the other one knowing that they're all numbers

Comment: update: i tried the same code but this time i used other columns from the database and it worked , what's the issues with the other one knowing that they're all numbers

Comment: Does it explain why it does not work with specific columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`JDBCCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html) API specifies:

> The SQL query must return at least two columns. The first column will be the category name and remaining columns values (each column represents a series).

This complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26941621/230513), which you have successfully adapted, illustrates the effect. The question then becomes,

> What's the issues with the other one knowing that they're all numbers?

The [`executeQuery()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/d03e68acaff59e7ba1b3573af3c45c9b028f715d/src/main/java/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.java#L207) source shows how each of the [`java.sql.Types`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) is mapped to a numeric value: a numeric type becomes a `Number` directly, a date type becomes a `Number` representing milliseconds from the Java [epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11871120/230513), and a character type is converted using `Double.valueOf()`; the `default` is `null`.

In this case, verify that `Prop_menages_Urbains_Proprietaires` has a SQL type that is suitable for conversion to a numeric value.

Comment: Yes exacty, the column was not a numeric type, thank you so much trashgod for the help.